# Funcion split csv importado en python

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, dataframe

Por ejemplo, en el `ID del CSV, "A-2523-abcd"`, la A tiene que representar el valor alemania.
B-2523-abcd la B tiene que representar Belgica, como puedo asignarles ese valor y luego agruparlos segun paises? Si tengo dos ID con la A(alemania) que me los agrupe y los otros 2 con la B(belgica) con la funcion split?

No he encontrado nada relacionado con esto.

```
import pandas as pd

mydataset = pd.read_csv('pruebapandas.csv',header=0)

df=pd.DataFrame(mydataset)

print("Dataframe Original")

df=df.assign(pais=paises.values)

print(mydataset.loc[mydataset['Matricula'].str.startswith("A")])

print(df.dtypes)

print(df)
```

Comment: no está claro el problema. por favor lee [ask] y proporciona un [example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consideremos el siguiente dataframe de ejemplo:

```py
import pandas as pd

mat_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Matricula": [
            "A-2523-abcd", "B-2523-fhtb", "P-5381-atek", "B-5528-abcd",
            "E-5200-iojd", "P-4331-atkd", "P-7731-ncth"
        ]
    }
)
```

`mat_df` queda así:

```
     Matricula
0  A-2523-abcd
1  B-2523-fhtb
2  P-5381-atek
3  B-5528-abcd
4  E-5200-iojd
5  P-4331-atkd
6  P-7731-ncth
```

Para extraer el nombre de los países, tenemos que definir los nombres. Por ejemplo, con otro dataframe:

```py
pai_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Codigo": ["A", "B", "E", "P"],
        "Pais": ["Alemania", "Bélgica", "España", "Portugal"]
    }
)
```

`pai_df` queda así:

```
  Codigo      Pais
0      A  Alemania
1      B   Bélgica
2      E    España
3      P  Portugal
```

A continuación, creamos una nueva columna llamada ***Codigo*** en `mat_df`. Los valores de esta nueva columna son el resultado de aplicar una función ***lambda*** (anónima) a cada uno de los valores de la columna ***Matricula*** de `mat_df`. Esta función devuelve el primer caracter del valor de *Matricula* con `x[0]`.

```py
mat_df["Codigo"] = mat_df["Matricula"].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

`mat_df` queda así:

```
     Matricula Codigo
0  A-2523-abcd      A
1  B-2523-fhtb      B
2  P-5381-atek      P
3  B-5528-abcd      B
4  E-5200-iojd      E
5  P-4331-atkd      P
6  P-7731-ncth      P
```

Añadimos los nombres de los países a `mat_df` haciendo un ***left merge*** entre `mat_df` y `pai_df` a través de la columna ***Codigo***:

```py
mat_df = mat_df.merge(pai_df, how="left", on="Codigo")
```

`mat_df` queda así:

```
     Matricula Codigo      Pais
0  A-2523-abcd      A  Alemania
1  B-2523-fhtb      B   Bélgica
2  P-5381-atek      P  Portugal
3  B-5528-abcd      B   Bélgica
4  E-5200-iojd      E    España
5  P-4331-atkd      P  Portugal
6  P-7731-ncth      P  Portugal
```

Finalmente, para agrupar el dataframe y obtener, por ejemplo, el número de matrículas por país, hacemos esto:

```py
gro_df = mat_df.groupby("Pais")[["Matricula"]].count()
```

`gro_df` queda así:

```
          Matricula
Pais               
Alemania          1
Bélgica           2
España            1
Portugal          3
```